# Why does the following rxjs call to switchMap give a type error?

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I am having trouble getting this code to type-check. It compiles and runs normally, and I am unclear whether I am missing something, or whether the type-checker is being stupid.

```
import * as Rx from 'rxjs'

const foo : Rx.Observable<number> =
    Rx.of<number>(1)
      .pipe<number>(
          switchMap<number,Rx.Observable<number>>(
              (n : number) => Rx.of<number>(n)
          )
      )
```

My real example is much more complicated, and as you can see, I have added many type annotations to try and help it, but it keeps leaving me with an uninstantiated free variable in the resulting type.

```
Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<number, T>' is not assignable to parameter
of type 'OperatorFunction<number, number>'.
   Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'number'. (tsx-tide)
```

Comment: no problem even if I write `const foo = Rx.of(1).pipe(switchMap( n => Rx.of(n)));`. I presume there is some wrong configuration for tsx-tide

Comment: Works for me on RxJs 6.4.0. What version of RxJs are you using? [See my stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-wu7s2v?file=index.ts)

Comment: Just let the compiler infer the types, no need to go so crazy. Also importing the whole of rxjs is a big fat bloat for your final build, just import what you need.

Comment: @Dorus wow, I am also on 6.4.0 as far as I am aware! Do you have your `tsconfig` around?

Comment: @AdrianBrand I only added the types for debugging purposes, I get the same error without any type annotations, but with the annotations I made the error more precise...

Answer (score 1):

In case this happens to anyone else, it fixed itself by changing my `tsconfig.json`. Not sure which field was causing problems but I have done the following changes:

- switch `module` from `amd` to `ESNext` (this might have helped)
- switch `target` from `es6` to `ES6` (I don't think this does anything)
- removed my `lib` which contained `dom`, `es2016`, `es2016.array.include`
- removes `"experimentalDecorators": true`